# Getting value from cell and his inside element JS

Tags: javascript

I want to get value like in subject, from cell but that cell have element `<a>1</a>` and in this element is the value.

I tried something like this:

```js
function filter(gvId) {
  var table = document.getElementById(gvId);

  for (var c = 1; c < table.rows[2].cells.length; c++) {
    for (var r = headerNumber; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
      var value = table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByClassName("a").innerHTML;
      console.log(value); //and it should show me :
      //1
      //2
      //3
      //4
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a>1</a>
      </td>
      <td><a>2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a>3</a>
      </td>
      <td><a>4</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything works greate without `<a>` tag inside cell. But now I don't know how to get this value.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `var value = table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByClassName("a").innerHTML;` is wrong, it should have been at least `var value = table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the problem is in a row:

```
var value = table.rows[r].cells[c].getElementsByClassName("a").innerHTML;
```

Because you're trying to match an element by class, but not by element tag. Link tag `<a>` has no className `a`. Your current code will work fine for: `<a class="a">1</a>` or `<div class="a"></div>`.

May be you should try something like `querySelector` instead? Like:

```
var value = table.rows[r].cells[c].querySelector('a').innerHTML;
```

Please, also check the MDN docs about [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

UPD: All the code could be simplified:

```
var contentLinks = table.querySelectorAll('td a');
contentLinks.forEach(function(item) {
    var value = item.innerHTML;
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text content of an element with `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

```
var value = table.rows[r].cells[c].textContent;
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)

Comment: Like previous. `value = undefined`